# Why don't I have any huts?

Tags: a-dark-room

All my huts are missing in "A Dark Room" but I still have people collecting wood and hunting, etc...

[image: hut error]

[image: people working]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing no huts, you just built the max amount of them. When reaching 80 people (what you got), you cannot build anymore huts. 80 people equal 20 huts. This is also stated with a message when the last hut has been build.

Go to your village tab and you'll see, they're still there.

When a hut burns down by accident, you can rebuild that one for the max amount of 1000 wood, the cost of hut nr 20 (= count*50 wood).

Source: My own experience. I tried this game out as I saw this question.